# Replace hyperbolic functions with trigonometric ones

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic

In the matrix exponential which I need for a certain problem, I often encounter terms like `Sinh[ Sqrt[ b^2 - a^2 ]]`.   In my problem, `a > b` and, therefore, the previous expression is actually `I Sin[ Sqrt[ a^2 - b^2]]`.  Is there a way to enforce Mathematica to use trigonometric functions instead of hyperbolic ones in expressions like these?

To give some context, I am writing equations of motion of a damped harmonic oscillator in vector form: $r'(t) = A. r(t)$, where `A = {{ 0 , o }, { - o , -g }}`.  The solution of this equation is given by `r[t_] = MatrixExp[ A t ].r0`.  The matrix exponential has multiple terms like `Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[g^2 - 4 o^2] t]`.  This is not too illustrative for a weakly damped harmonic oscillator, for which the frequency `o >> g` (damping rate).

Comment: You are probably forgetting an $i$: $\sinh(\sqrt{b^2-a^2}) = i \sin(\sqrt{a^2-b^2})$.

Comment: @Domen true, my bad

Comment: Is there a reason `ReplaceAll` would not work?

Comment: @userrandrand do you mean something like `Cosh[x_ Sqrt@y_ ] -> Cosh[ I x Sqrt[ -y]]`?  No reason, but I was worried that the patterns I can come up with are either too imprecise, like the one above, or too precise.

Comment: @AndR depends on the full expression. Too precise is maybe fairly safe. Too imprecise might lead to unwanted substitutions. I would have turned the equality by Domen into a replacement rule like `/. Sinh[ Sqrt[ b^2 - a^2 ]]->I Sin[ Sqrt[ a^2 - b^2]]` but maybe that leads to an issue somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Assuming[x > y > 0,
  {Sqrt[x - y], Sqrt[y - x]} // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify]
(*    {Sqrt[x - y], I Sqrt[x - y]}    *)

Assuming[a > b > 0,
  Sinh[Sqrt[b^2 - a^2]] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify]
(*    I Sin[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]]    *)

Assuming[o > g > 0,
  Cosh[1/2 Sqrt[g^2 - 4 o^2] t] // ComplexExpand // FullSimplify]
(*    Cos[1/2 Sqrt[-g^2 + 4 o^2] t]    *)
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of ComplexExpand myself? Thanks a lot, this is exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @AndR note that the `FullSimplify` might make the code slow if your matrices are large and complex.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to write a function for this purpose

```
f[expr_, opt_] := Module[{pos},
  pos = Position[expr, Sqrt[u_]][[1, 1]];
  Simplify[
   If[expr[[pos, 1]] < 0, 
    ReplacePart[expr, pos -> I*Sqrt[-expr[[pos, 1]]]]], opt]]
```

Then, taking your function:

```
expr = Sinh[Sqrt[b^2 - a^2]];
```

one finds

```
f[expr, {a > b, b > 0}]

(*  I Sin[Sqrt[a^2 - b^2]]  *)
```

However, in a more complex case, one maybe needs to modify this function to account for peculiarity of the expression.

Have fun!